Swift Concurrency capturing self weakly in actor
In the example below, when self is captured weakly, Swift raises an error that the member function call needs to be called with await. Expanding the error says:

Calls to instance method 'doSomething()' from outside of its actor context are implicitly asynchronous

Changing the capture of self to strong makes the error go away.
actor MyActor {
    func launchTaskThatDoesSomething() {
        Task { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return }

            doSomething() // error: Expression is 'async' but is not marked with 'await'
        }
    }

    private func doSomething() {}
}

My question is, what is the difference? Why is the call "outside of its actor context" when self is captured weakly?

Fascinating question. An unrelated observation, though: Why use the [weak self] capture list at all? We used it a lot in legacy asynchronous patterns to either (a) to prevent strong reference cycles (not an issue here); or (b) to prevent a closure which is called at some future time from keeping a strong reference longer than necessary (which, again, is not an issue here, as the task will generally start immediately). Weak capture lists just don’t have quite the same utility in Swift concurrency as they had in legacy code bases. There are edge cases, but not here.

@Rob It's (b), not having another strong reference. You're right though, using [weak self] is probably not required here, still I've found it gives me some ease of mind knowing that a piece of asynchronous code will not keep my instance alive any longer than needed.

The thing is, the task will generally launch quickly. It’s the doSomething that likely will take a lot of time, but at that point it’s too late. The strong reference is now established. In Swift concurrency, the pattern is cancellation, not weak references.

First, consider this very simple code
actor MyActor {
    func f() {
        let x = self
        x.doSomething()
    }

    private func doSomething() {}
}

Swift will claim that x.doSomething() also needs an await. This is because (at the time of writing) Swift does not do data flow analysis to determine that x and self refers to the same actor. As far as Swift is concerned, x could totally be a different instance of MyActor, so calling x.doSomething() potentially involves an actor hop.
It is a similar situation when you capture self. Swift emits the same error message for:
Task { [x = self] in
    x.doSomething()
}

[weak self] is similar. You can think of it as assigning self to some variable of type MyActor? that also happens to be called self:
Task { 
    [weak `self` = self] in
    self?.doSomething() // same error
}

In your code, you bound this MyActor? to yet another variable (using guard let), also called self.
The only exception is [self] or [self = self]. Swift doesn't treat this as assigning self to another variable.
This behaviour was reported as an issue and is also discussed on the Swift Forums.
For now, just add await there. At runtime, Swift will know that they are the same actor and will not do an actor hop.

Interesting, this behavior only happens with actor types. A class isolated to a global actor (including the main actor) will not exhibit this behavior.

@Rob That's not surprising, is it? It is much easier to determine isolation for global actors because there is only one instance. Actor types can have multiple instances and they can be assigned to variables. In this case, Swift needs to determine if the code isolated to some "random instance" (there's no special case made for [weak self]) captured in a closure. There is no data flow analysis implemented for that.

Personally, I find it surprising. Task {…} launches a new top-level task on behalf of the current actor. But what we’re effectively seeing is “no, if you use weak reference to self, then it does not entirely behave that way, unless that actor happens to be a global actor, and then it does.” It is just weird. I’m not diminishing the complexity for the Swift team, but the inconsistency defies any reasonable expectations. It’s not a big deal, because we so rarely use weak capture lists with Swift concurrency (and therefore is likely low on their list), but it is surprising, nonetheless.
